# How to prevent Xcode 4 from crashing with git branch when the project file changes?

Tags: xcode, crash, branch, xcode4, git-branch

When the project file is different between two branches (say, we added a new source file), switching git branches causes Xcode 4 to crash. What's a good solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same thing.  The only workaround I've found is to close Xcode, do any branch changes I need, then reopen Xcode.  Not the best solution, especially if you're switching branches frequently, but it seems to work.  Ultimately it's probably something Apple will have to address as Joshua mentioned.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If it's crashing, it's a bug and needs to be reported to Apple via http://bugreporter.apple.com so they can fix it.

Comment: I'm certain people have reported crashes. I've submitted more than a few reports myself for flat-out crashes (and other unsavory behavior). Since not all crashes are the same issue, however, don't rely on "others" to do it. Apple needs to know about all of them (and how often they happen). Also, only Apple knows who submitted what (the information is not public). Take-home message: file bug reports; don't rely on others to do it.